# ionic/angular - get data from database - data loaded, but no output on site

Tags: angularjs, database, ionic-framework, request

i try to do an database-request and want to see the output on site.
The data is successfully loaded, but the output doesn't work. I just see nothing in the .

Here is the code of my controller:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope) {})

.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, pizzaService) {
  $scope.pizzas = pizzaService.all();
})

.controller('ChatsCtrl', function($scope, Chats) {
  $scope.chats = Chats.all();
  $scope.remove = function(chat) {
    Chats.remove(chat);
  }
})

.controller('ChatDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Chats) {
  $scope.chat = Chats.get($stateParams.chatId);
})


.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.settings = {
    enableFriends: true
  };

});
```

And here to code of my service:

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])
.factory('pizzaService', function($http) {
var pizzas = {};
  $http.get("http://localhost/whatever/www/php/load_Pizzas.php").success(function(data){
  this.pizzas = data;
  console.log('success - pizzas loaded');
  console.log(this.pizzas);
  });

  return {
    all: function() {
      return this.pizzas;
    }
  };
});
```

And here the code of the html-site:

```
<ion-view view-title="Pizzas">
<ion-content>
<label class="item item-input">
<input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Suchtext">
</label>
<p ng-show="search">Du suchst gerade nach: {{search}}</p>
<ion-search placeholder="ion Suche" filter="search"></ion-search>
<ion-list>

<ion-item class="item-divider">Pizzas</ion-item>

<ion-item ng-repeat="pizza in pizzas.pizzas | filter:search" class="item-remove-animate item-icon-right">
<h2>{{pizza.name}}</h2>
<p>Preis: {{pizza.price}} Euro</p>
<i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
<ion-option-button class="button-assertive" >
Löschen
</ion-option-button>
</ion-item>

</ion-list>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

What is the failure?
Here a pictue of the console.log:
[picture](http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=bd4120-1435750698.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller.js

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope) {})

.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, pizzaService) {
  pizzaService.all().then(function(payload) {
     $scope.pizzas = payload;
     console.log(payload);
  });
})

.controller('ChatsCtrl', function($scope, Chats) {
  $scope.chats = Chats.all();
  $scope.remove = function(chat) {
    Chats.remove(chat);
  }
})

.controller('ChatDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Chats) {
  $scope.chat = Chats.get($stateParams.chatId);
})

.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.settings = {
    enableFriends: true
  };

});
```

Service.js

```
    angular.module('starter.services', [])
    .factory('pizzaService', function($http) {

      return {
        all: function() {
          // Return promise (async callback)
          return $http.get("http://localhost/soundso/www/php/load_Pizzas.php");
        }
      };
    });
```

test html

```
<ion-view view-title="Pizzas">
  <ion-content>
    <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Suchtext">
    </label>
    <p ng-show="search">Du suchst gerade nach: {{search}}</p>
    <ion-search placeholder="ion Suche" filter="search"></ion-search>
    <ion-list>

      <ion-spinner ng-show="!pizzas" icon="spiral"></ion-spinner>

      <ion-item class="item-divider">Pizzas</ion-item>

      <ion-item ng-repeat="pizza in pizzas | filter:search" class="item-remove-animate item-icon-right">
        <h2>{{pizza.name}}</h2>
        <p>Preis: {{pizza.price}} Euro</p>
        <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
        <ion-option-button class="button-assertive" >
          Löschen
        </ion-option-button>
      </ion-item>

    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And here a screenshot
[image]

Comment: Ah, simple — there you return a data inside payload object. Just need to update a scope from $scope.pizzas = payload; to $scope.pizzas = payload.data;

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are make a request from controller to service and didn't wait until data will be fetched, so you are get empty object because instantly return  `this.pizzas`. Instead need to wait until request to be finished and then append it to required scope.

**Controller:**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope) {})

// Get promise and wait until data will be fetched, then push to scope.
.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, pizzaService) {
  pizzaService.all().then(function(payload) {
     $scope.pizzas = payload;
  });

})

.controller('ChatsCtrl', function($scope, Chats) {
  $scope.chats = Chats.all();
  $scope.remove = function(chat) {
    Chats.remove(chat);
  }
})

.controller('ChatDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Chats) {
  $scope.chat = Chats.get($stateParams.chatId);
})


.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.settings = {
    enableFriends: true
  };

});
```

**Service:**

*Note:* Angular $http function is a promise, so you don't need to wrap it with deferred $q methods.

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])
.factory('pizzaService', function($http) {

  return {
    all: function() {
      // Return promise (async callback)
      return $http.get("http://localhost/whatever/www/php/load_Pizzas.php");
    }
  };
});
```

**View:**

*Note:* You can use [ion-spinner](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSpinner/) to wait until data will be ready
 and / or [ion-refresher](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionRefresher/)

```
 <ion-view view-title="Pizzas">
    <ion-content>
    <label class="item item-input">
    <input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Suchtext">
    </label>
    <p ng-show="search">Du suchst gerade nach: {{search}}</p>
    <ion-search placeholder="ion Suche" filter="search"></ion-search>
    <ion-list>

<ion-spinner ng-show="!pizzas" icon="spiral"></ion-spinner>

    <ion-item class="item-divider">Pizzas</ion-item>

    <ion-item ng-repeat="pizza in pizzas | filter:search" class="item-remove-animate item-icon-right">
    <h2>{{pizza.name}}</h2>
    <p>Preis: {{pizza.price}} Euro</p>
    <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
    <ion-option-button class="button-assertive" >
    Löschen
    </ion-option-button>
    </ion-item>

    </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
```

Comment: i see a bit more, but still not working. i post an screenshot.