# How do I get the data from a view to another view in ionic?

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax, codeigniter, ionic-framework

I have followed this tutorial [ionic/angular - get data from database - data loaded, but no output on site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31160043/ionic-angular-get-data-from-database-data-loaded-but-no-output-on-site)
on how to retrieve data from database and show it in ionic but the problem is the data can only be seen in one view and I dont know how to view it in another view

[screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQYaW.png) - I have successfully  display the recipes in my ionic from my database and when I click the pen icon it should be displaying the recipe name, ingredients and more

[screencap 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRNKo.png) - but when I click it it doesnt show any data.

here's my code for viewing data :

user_model.php (codeigniter - model )

```
public function user_recipe_data()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('usersrecipes');
        $this->db->join('user', 'user.user_id = usersrecipes.user_id');
        $this->db->where('usersrecipes.user_id = 12 ');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Main.php ( codeigniter - controller )

```
public function get_user_recipe_data()
{
    $postdata = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $user_recipe = $this->User_model->user_recipe_data();
    echo json_encode($user_recipe);
}
```

RecipeService.js (ionic)

.factory('getRecipeService', function($http){

```
return {
    all: function() {
      return $http.get("http://localhost/admin-recipick/api/Main/get_user_recipe_data");
    },
    get: function(Recipe_ID) {
        q = $http.get("http://localhost/admin-recipick/api/Main/get_user_recipe_data");
  for (var i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
    if (q[i].id === parseInt(Recipe_ID)) {
      return q[i];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
};
```

});

controller.js (ionic)

```
 getRecipeService.all().then(function(payload) {
 $scope.userrecipedata = payload.data;
 console.log(payload);
});
```

profile.html ( ionic )

```
 <ion-list>
              <ion-item ng-repeat="recipe in userrecipedata" class="item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right"  type="item-textu-wrap" href="#/app/recipes/{{recipe.Recipe_ID}}">
                <img ng-src="img/food/porkmenudo.jpg">

                <h2>{{recipe.Recipename}}</h2>
                <p>{{recipe.Ingredients}}</p>
                <i class="icon ion-edit"></i>
                <ion-option-button class="button-assertive" ng-click="remove(recipe)">
                  Delete
                </ion-option-button>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
```

recipe-detail.html ( ionic - in this html I want to display the data here also but it shows no data in the input type. What should I do?)

```
    <div class="list">

        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Index Name</span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="recipe.Recipe_ID">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
           <span class="input-label">Recipe Name</span>
             <input type="text" ng-model="recipe.Recipename">
         </label>
         <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Ingredients</span>
              <input type="text" ng-model="recipe.Ingredients">
         </label>
         <label class="item item-input item-select">
            <span class="input-label">Cooking Time</span>
              <select ng-model="recipe.Cookingtime">
                 <option value="20mins">20mins</option>
                 <option value="30mins">30mins</option>
                 <option value="1hr">1hr</option>
               </select>
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input">
              <textarea placeholder="PROCEDURE" rows="12" ng-model="recipe.Procedure">
              </textarea>
          </label>
           <button class="button button-block button-assertive h1" ng-click="AddRecipe()">Update Recipe</button>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use http for controller

```
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $http, $stateParams) {
$scope.userrecipedata = [];

$http.get('http://localhost/admin-recipick/api/Main/get_user_recipe_data').success(function(response){
    $scope.userrecipedata = response;
}); 
})
```

Comment: It works sir @B.Nadesh kumar but I want to edit the data from another view which is the recipe-detail.html, how would I do that?

Comment: use this link post to codeigniter  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485354/angular-http-post-to-php-and-undefined